# Is it possible to merge two teams of final rankings with one team having 7 members, and the second team having 24 members?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics

Is it possible to merge two teams of final rankings with one team having 7 members, and the second team having 24 members? Is there a formula to provide one total overall ranking between the groups?

Team 1 has 7 people
Team 2 has 24 people

both teams have their own set of rankings
We rank using relative reference for both groups containing 4 categories each. Each category is scored among the teams (7 & 24) using a relative reference scoring scale (0-100; highest ranked receives 100 points). For each team, we rank the weighted score among the 4 categories.

We would like to combine these two groups to have one final, overall rank.

Is there a formula to provide one total overall ranking between the groups?

Thank you

Comment: Absolutely none of your tags seem appropriate for this question.

Comment: Definitely agreed.. If you tag the appropriate categories, then the corresponding experts in that area can help you.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of formulas.  Whether they are "fair" or what you want is up to you.  You can just place one team above the other.  You can merge the two lists based on individual total score, or scores in one category.  You can rank the players based on the percentage of the team they beat, so you flip a coin between the two bottoms, but the next three to bottom of 24 come below the next to bottom of 7.